# Customer is getting "Not Secure" error on our payment page using Chrome, but I cannot replicate it

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, certificate

Our website has thousands of customers who make payments, but this is the first time I've heard from a customer that our payment page is showing up as not secure.

My colleagues and I have tried to replicate this but we haven't been able to. As you can see in the screenshot from our customer, it's showing the certificate as OK.  This is concerning because she called to make sure it was safe for her to enter her credit card information, and I wasn't sure what to say. I'm not sure how many other customers might be having this same issue.

All I have from her is the screenshot. Can anyone determine what is causing this?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: BTW, if someone uses HTTP instead of HTTPS it does automatically redirect to HTTPS.

Comment: Also, as you can see in the screenshot, it's not just the payment page which is showing non-secure. This seems to be happening to her on our homepage as well.

Comment: Chrome has recently changed the rules what it considers a "safe" https website.  What determines a "safe" website entirely depends on the certificate being used.  As the screenshot indicates the traffic is indeed encrypted, due to the fact there is an SSL certificate, but chrome only displays "https" on the browser URL when the website is considered safe.  You should consider generating a new certificate for your website using the current best practices.  You will have to test several versions of Chrome with your website to determine if you can identify what version the client was using.

Comment: Once you have that information, update your question with the affected version of Chrome, and information about your certificate.  There are too many possible reasons for this particular warning to generate an answer without the information.  My properly configured PC has the same warning for your website by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox loads with no warnings:

[image]

Chrome looks okay *at first*...

[image]

...but choosing `Load unsafe scripts`...

[image]

... causes the problem to be replicated in Chrome:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! We fixed this, and I'm waiting for her to retry.

Comment: Glad you got it fixed! I noticed I can't reproduce the error in Chrome anymore. It's working great now.